# How to get col/row number when the cursor selected current cell in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How to get col/row number when the cursor selected current cell

[image: https://i.imgur.com/i97YaG2.jpg]

Comment: not possible on mouse cursor select. it would be possible on some input, tho

Comment: can you write this script

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is **not** possible to do in Google Sheets, not even with the help of Google Apps Script. What you would need in theory is a Google Apps Script trigger that runs every time a new cell is selected, but this type of trigger does not exist/is not supported. See here for [supported trigger types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers).

Comment: Thanks Florian Minges

I another question.

How to get value the cursor selected current cell

[Screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZloI.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Following the same logic as in my answer, that is also not possible.